# Instagram graph API, fetching old id format

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

this week, the https://graph.instagram.com/me endpoint has been returning a different ID format.

There is a flow in my app that is dependent on those ids, and I had no idea that IG was changing the ids at all.

I tried to use older versions of the api, by using https://graph.instagram.com/v10.0/me so i can get the old id, look up the info in my DB and migrate it to the id provided by newer API versions.

Unfortunately, it seems like even older versions of the API are returning the new id?

If that's the case I am not sure how to migrate the information for my users, and I am already receiving user support requests for access to lost content.